# React onChange not working for input inside functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, sweetalert

I have done this a million time and never had this problem and i don't know what i am doing wrong.
I have a simple input field and have a hook `useState` of `amount` and `setAmount` and I am using `handleChange` function to update this but the `handleChange` function is not triggering

```
const CustomAmount = () => {
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e); // This is not working either

    setAmount(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="custom-amount-container">
      <h4>Enter your desired amount</h4>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="custom-amount"
        data-test="custom-amount-input"
        value={amount}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried putting it inside the `onChange` prop directly but still no luck and also normally if `onChange` function doesn't work it doesn't change value but in this case value is being changed inside the input field

Also I am using this component inside `sweetalert` modal

```
 const customAmountModal = () => {
    return swal(<CustomAmount />);
  };
```

Comment: do you mean `e.target.value` (without the `s`) ?

Comment: Oh sorry about that its not working either way and its a typo when i was copying ill edit it out

Comment: it works https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-gagarin-r6xjv?file=/src/App.js are you getting any errors? is this your exact code?

Comment: @SulmanAzhar I haven't used sweetalert but are you passing the component right ? Possible mistake could be there.

Comment: This is my exact code and thats why its so confusing like this is basic stuff and i know i am not doing anything wrong and no errors. Maybe its because of sweetalert?

Comment: yeah where does it say you can do `swal(<Component />)` ? the docs say you pass an object https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/sCR3WO4.png
I saw this part and thought why not i mean jsx so it should work technically. Or am i missing something?
Also this is the codesandbox please take a look
https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-tree-1lyg3?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been trying to debug the cause of event handlers not getting invoked for the component that is wrapped inside `swal` but couldn't. So as per my limited understanding the **React Synthetic Events** are not getting triggered for such components but if you use the **Native DOM Events**, you can achieve the same functionality like so :-

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import swal from "@sweetalert/with-react";
import "./styles.css";

const CustomAmount = () => {
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setAmount(e.target.value);
  };

  console.log("render", amount);

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.addEventListener("input", handleChange);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="custom-amount-container">
      <h4>Enter your desired amount</h4>

      <input
        type="number"
        name="custom-amount"
        data-test="custom-amount-input"
        value={amount}
        ref={inputRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const customAmountModal = () => {
    return swal(<CustomAmount />);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button onClick={customAmountModal}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-jang-jrgex?file=/src/App.js

Still would like to know why the **React** way doesn't work. Haven't really worked with `swal` so unaware of the use-cases it's made for.

Comment: You are the best man. although it is doing exactly what i need i am getting this warning because there is not onChange method for the input

Comment: No worries man. And yes you will get that warning since you're out of the React event flow now so it's telling you that the `value` might never change so instead opt for `defaultValue` or make it **readOnly**. Honestly maybe use a library which allows you to do things in a much simpler `React` way or check if there is a newer version to help you. What I gave is simply a workaround. Already upvoted your question so maybe we get something better.

Comment: You are right. I am using the swal for modal type work in this situation so i think i might use any other library modal or create my own. Anyway thanks for the help this was informative

Answer (score 2):

This is currently a known issue with swal and react 17:
https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/950

The author is aware and says he'll push the updates soon enough.

Feel free to upvote/watch the issue for an update on this.

Answer (score 1):

It's becauese the SyntheticEvent objects are pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the event handler has been called.

Now you are reusing event object, firstly is console.log function and then in setState.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do

```
onChange={e => setAmount(e.target.value)
```

Comment: No this won't work as it is the same this as onChange={handleChange} and yes i have tried it basically the events aren't triggering